# Is ".mdx" file format only supported/used by React.js

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, next.js, svelte, mdxjs

Almost all the references online mention the use of [MDX](https://mdxjs.com/) with React.js. Even though other frameworks or libraries support MDX (with help of components), I haven't specifically seen the use of ".mdx" file formats outside of React.

The support of ".mdx" files in Gatsby and Next.js allows us to create a separate folder for the blog posts and have them stored anywhere (CMS, Github etc...) which helps in organizing. And the file extension of ".mdx" itself is pretty straight-forward and self-explanatory even for a beginner to grasp the concept.

So I was just wondering - If I would like to use mdx files, am I limited to React.js? Is it possible to use Svelte, Vue, Angular as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use mdx outside of React but not everywhere, Check out this guides I hope they help!

- mdx for Vue.js: https://mdxjs.com/guides/vue/
- mdx for Svelte(MDsveX): https://madewithsvelte.com/mdsvex

Answer (score 1):

`MDX` as such is specifically for React because it uses `JSX` to define it's component.

I am sure there are alternatives for other frameworks, as a Svelte user myself I know that at least Svelte has [MDSVEX](https://mdsvex.com/) which is basically the same.

Comment: MDsveX mentions the use of `.svx` file formats. Does it also support `.mdx`?

Comment: It is almost the same, markdown with svelte components inside. But a pure mdx file probably not no.